# Sort files in a folder and its subfolders by type and size

Tags: bash, file, size, aggregate, file-extension

I have to count a huge number of files in a directory and subdirectories recursively by extension and get the total size for each extension.

**I do not want to see individual files with their type and size next to them.**

For example, this would be one potential output:

```
JPEG - 123 Files - 321MB Total;
AVI - 321 Files - 123MB Total;
MP4 - 111 Files - 111MB Total;
```

I have tried using `ls -lshR`, then piping the result to `grep`, but I can't create a script file to parse the results, due to the limits of the environment I'm working in. I'm stuck on actually counting and totalling the sizes from the result of `ls -lshR | grep ".txt"`, in a single command.

Comment: If you already posted a question, and got no (good) response, why are you posting the question again? Also, did you see the pretty alright lead from fromthestone?

Comment: Because maybe the second time around other people will look into it, maybe this time I've asked a clearer question, hopefully. If you have anything to add or underline regarding a specific answer on a previous question, please do it there, not here.

Comment: Alrighty, though I heartily disagree that reasking a question is ever a good thing; if it didn't get any attention the first time, it's unlikely it'll get any more the second. Now, feedback on _this_ question: Too broad. StackOverflow doesn't write your code for you. You've done more than some by showing an example output, but post what you've tried so far or what you have and where you're getting stuck. At least demonstrate that you've done a little research and put a little effort into this beyond asking a question.

Comment: I have, and unfortunately the solution provided by fromthestone previously could work, but I'm not able to parse the results from ls to a file simply due to the environment setup - I cant create a file to parse the results to, so it must be done in a single query.

ls -lshR boo/ | grep ".txt" does half the job, now I presume I have to think of a way to sum the results in the first field from the displayed files for a grand total when the command finishes.

Comment: So put that into the question! Rather than phrasing it as "here's my question I asked before that I'm asking again", phrase it as "Here's a question I asked before; I'm trying to implement a solution I got from that question, but I'm getting stuck here."

Comment: Question has been edited as advised. Thank you for your patience and for your time with the edit, I do appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to help (and get a couple extra reputation points)

Comment: you're complicating your solution by using the `-h` option to `ls`. Human readable is find for humans, but it will require extra parsing and processing to total (as per my local filesystem) 38+1.5K+2,9M. I'd recommend  totaling bytes and then divide the sum by 1024*1024 and append MB to the end. Unless you expect GBs to be the dominant file size. Pipe your `ls -lsR` output to awk and use something like  `jpgSum+=$5` for each type of file. use the END{... } block to print it out. There are ways to make this completely data driven, but get a basic version to work first. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter, thank you for your reply!

I've went with the following solution: 

    find boo/ -name '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{ Total += $5} END { print Total }'

This gives a result - 95921009. The -h option isn't present, so logically this is in bytes. Turning this into MB would equal to ~96MB, am I correct in all this?

Comment: I get ~91MB, using 1048576 as the result of 1024*1024. Maybe I'm wrong about my MB math, haven't had to worry about that in a few years now. But ~91, ~96, probably close enough for what you're doing either way. Good bit of research finding the `find` front end. Keep hacking! Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can boil your commented solution down even further,

```
 find /boo -ls \
 | awk '/.*\.txt/{txtTot+=$6}; /.*\.mp4/{mp4Tot+=$6} END {print "Txt Tot=" txtTot "\nMP4 Tot=" mp4Tot}'
```

This gets all files under `/boo`, The awk `/.*\.txt/` etc are reg expression to match only lines with `.txt`. same for `.mp4`. Keep adding as many as you need. Any that you don't care about are skipped in the processing.

(your `find` may put the file size in a different field num, just look at the output and change references to $6 as needed).

Then next thing would be to use awk arrays to dynamically total file sizes by type, but read some more about awk before you worry about.

(I don't have a way to test this right now, so there may be a few minor syntax things left over. Depending on version of awk, you may get a useful error message or not ;-/ )

IHTH